# How to assert "no calls to an object have been made"?

Tags: c#, .net, fakeiteasy

How to assert that no calls to an object have been made using FakeItEasy?

I tried:

```
A.CallTo(() => _myObj).MustNotHaveHappened();
```

That does not work though, it throws the following exception:

> System.ArgumentException : The specified expression is not a method call or property getter.

How to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the mechanism described in [Specify a call to configure any method or property](http://fakeiteasy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/specifying-a-call-to-configure/#specifying-a-call-to-any-method-or-property) and just pass the fake to `A.CallTo`:

```
A.CallTo(_myObj).MustNotHaveHappened();
```